# How to set sound input to the sound that's coming out of the speakers?

Tags: 11.10, sound, microphone

I remember that I could do this by messing with input devices at the sound configuration menus, but it doesn't work anymore. I want to make the default input be a virtual mic that's the sound that's coming out of the speakers, while still being able to listen to it.

Answer (score 1):

[This solution](http://blog.stebalien.com/2009/03/howto-ones-linux-computer-with.html) allows you to record what you're hearing, but I don't know how to make it a default setting for anything. The instructions, updated for 11.10:

- Install gnome recorder and volume control: `sudo apt-get install gnome-media pavucontrol`
- Start recording: `gnome-sound-recorder` and click on the record button
- Start your audio program
- Set record source: `pavucontrol` and open the Recording tab and pick the monitor interface of your output
  [image: pavucontrol]

It seems that the gnome recorder defaults to that device afterwards, but I don't know if this persists across boots (or is indeed what you wanted).